# React default props for array property in required object

Tags: reactjs, react-proptypes

I have an array as non-required property in required object and I want to give a default value for this array.

```
const { classes, eItem } = props;

eItem: PropTypes.shape({
   eList: PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.shape({
      id: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
      nameSurname: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
      img: PropTypes.string,
   })),
}).isRequired,

Example.defaultProps = {
   eItem: { 
      eList: [] 
   },
};
```

I have written defaultProps like that, but I see that eList is undefined in the console.

How can I give a default value for eList as an empty array?

Comment: Can you also show the related code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this shape

```
ReactComponent.propTypes={
  eItem:PropTypes.shape({
    eList: PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.shape({

      id:PropTypes.number ,
      nameSurname: PropTypes.string,
      img: PropTypes.string
    }).isRequired

  })}
```

with adding the defaultProps as this shape

```
ReactComponent.defaultProps = {
  eItem: { 
  eList: [
{id:10,nameSurname:"ddddfd",img:"mjjkjkjskdj"}
],
}
```

Comment: Ok. This way force to give an initial value when I use this component but I don't want to define any eList prop when I use. I want to define a default value in the component if eList is undefined.

Comment: But now, eList has a one item and still comes undefined when initializing. I want to an empty array.

Comment: if you want empty to remove the isRequired  you can add the number of the eList add what you need as[{id:10,nameSurname:"ddddfd",img:"mjjkjkjskdj"}
,{id:11,nameSurname:"mdmdmd",img:"mjjkjkjskdjdf"}]

Answer (score 1):

This is a best practice that writes default props for your noun-required items, because of your warranty to your component that required props are passed to them.

So, in your case, remove redundant and unnecessary default props, then pass a default item to your default props like:

```
Example.defaultProps = {
   eItem: { 
      eList: [
         id: "Some default number",
         nameSurname: "Some default text",
         img: "default path for a placeholder item ",
      ] 
   },
};
```

Comment: It isn't an empty array like that and I still see that eList is undefined in the console. By the way eList is an array, It's not an object.